# How can I dynamically change an image from an admin area?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, flash

Here's the deal: I am working on a site that provides information for art buyers. Pricing, where to buy and things like that. The page is done in php, mysql, and some jQuery here and there.

One of the things they want to implement is a **live stream of auctions**. What they want is something like this:

[image: example of live stream]

Where on the left you'd see the stream -instead of the black block- and on the right, the image of the work that is **currently being sold**, with the artist name, title and price. That's what I need help with. The image on the left should change as the auction progresses.

What I need is to have and option in the admin area on the page, where the administrator can select the image to display. So, to implement this, I would need to:

1. Connect to the database to get the information: pictures, data, etc.
2. Loop trough the record to get a list. From that list, the user will select the image he wants shown on the webpage.
3. Have the admin area send the image to be displayed  to the page, and have the page *change it dynamically*, without the user having to refresh the page.

The first two points are no problem, what I'm not quite sure how to do is the third one. Flash? Some from of Javascript? I leaning towards flash, but anything will do. I'm sure what I'm asking for is nothing that hasn't been done before, but my *google-fu* has failed me on this one. I don't need copy and paste code, if you could point me to a tutorial on this, or the basics tools I'd need, that's great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **polling** when you periodically check if there is any change (you make an ajax query in every say 5 seconds).

The other, cooler method is **comet**, when you have a server, which sends a message to the client (browser). In this model a you can use a long XHR or a hidden iframe. Your server side must be a bit more intricate, this is not a request-response model PHP was made for. But now days PHP has the ability to open sockets and work as a network server. Read about the [socket function in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) for details.